# Enabling Device Admin as App Settings

Tags: android, android-preferences, application-settings

I am trying to develop a security application , I want initially to display list of installed apps and on item click of list , its required permissions.

I have successfully made the app till permissions. Now , I want to disable camera , internet, etc, using Device admin API, I wish to include "Disable Camera" option in the settings of "AppsList" ie my list of installed apps Application ?

Can someone guide me how to do it ? Should I need to use preferences ? Any help appreciated,new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

On developers.android.com [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#pwd) it describes as

> **Disable camera**
>
> Beginning with Android 4.0, you can disable the camera. Note that this
>   doesn't have to be a permanent disabling. The camera can be
>   enabled/disabled dynamically based on context, time, and so on.
>
> You control whether the camera is disabled by using the
>   setCameraDisabled() method. For example, this snippet sets the camera
>   to be enabled or disabled based on a checkbox setting:

**Code**

```
 private CheckBoxPreference mDisableCameraCheckbox; DevicePolicyManager
     mDPM; ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample; ...
     mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample,
     mDisableCameraCheckbox.isChecked());
```